# How to split a string in between square brackets like below

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split the string

```
[{"starDate":"","endDate":"","relativeDays":,"cronExpression":""},{"starDate":"","endDate":"","relativeDays":,"cronExpression":""}]
```

to

```
{"starDate":"","endDate":"","relativeDays":,"cronExpression":""}
{"starDate":"","endDate":"","relativeDays":,"cronExpression":""}
```

Comment: That looks like valid json. Couldn't you parse it instead of using some error-prone string manipulation? EDIT: no, it's not valid json, "relativeDays" is missing its value.

Comment: What do you want to split the string into, just two strings or do you want to create a collection with key/value pairs?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one-liner work out for you, since it's not clear whether you want two strings or one string with explicit line breaks

```
String str = "[{\"starDate\":\"\",\"endDate\":\"\",\"relativeDays\":,\"cronExpression\":\"\"},{\"starDate\":\"\",\"endDate\":\"\",\"relativeDays\":,\"cronExpression\":\"\"}]";
        
str = String.join("},", str.replaceAll("^\\[|]$+", "").split("},"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally do this the proper way using JSON parsing if it applies.

Meanwhile, for this very specific case, you can use a Regular Expression to extract the parts you need (Example in Java) :

```
String input = "[{\"starDate\":\"\",\"endDate\":\"\",\"relativeDays\":,\"cronExpression\":\"\"},{\"starDate\":\"\",\"endDate\":\"\",\"relativeDays\":,\"cronExpression\":\"\"}]";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\{[^\\}]*\\})").matcher(input);
while( matcher.find() )
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

This will result in :

```
{"starDate":"","endDate":"","relativeDays":,"cronExpression":""}
{"starDate":"","endDate":"","relativeDays":,"cronExpression":""}
```